# Double trouble, subtracting

Tags: c#, double

Im getting totally wrong when calling CorrectDecimals with the following parameters:

203,30 - 203,00. Gives me: 0.30000000000001137 (the variable double d). With my mathematical skills it should just be 0.3

```
string a = CorrectDecimals("203,30", "203,00", "12");

public static string CorrectDecimals(string unitPrice, string netAmount, string length)
{
            double unitP = (Double.Parse(unitPrice));
            double netAmoun = (Double.Parse(netAmount));
            double d = unitP - netAmoun;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with *financial* data (prices, amount etc.) use `Decimal` instead of `double`/`float`:

```
   string a = CorrectDecimals("203,30", "203,00", "12");

   public static string CorrectDecimals(string unitPrice, string netAmount, string length)
   {
       decimal unitP = decimal.Parse(unitPrice);
       decimal netAmoun = decimal.Parse(netAmount);
       decimal d = unitP - netAmoun;
```

In case you *have to* implement the routine in `double`, use *formatting*:

```
       double d = unitP - netAmoun;
       ...
       // 2 digits after decimal point
       string result = d.ToString("F2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string CorrectDecimals(string unitPrice, string netAmount, string length)
    {
        decimal unitP = (decimal.Parse(unitPrice));
        decimal netAmoun = (decimal.Parse(netAmount));
        decimal d = unitP - netAmoun;
        string result = d.ToString();

        return result;
    }
```

Use decimal instead of double.